# Select SQL query to get data from multiple tables and view in one table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

The problem that rise over is ,looping of checkout time automaticaly before the employers key in the data of checkout time.

The checkout column will be empty after key in of check in time but it automatically generates checkout time and for the following days, it pulls  data from the previous days and duplicated the time.I just suspect that , there will be some errors in calling of data from 3 table in one query :
  * tbl_student
  * time
  * check_out

```html
Table 1 ( time )

id       id_number1      date1        check_in             
-----------------------------------------------------
30        10001       2018-02-04       22:07:59

31        10002       2018-02-04       22:08:09

32        10001       2018-02-05      08:21:10 




Table 2 ( check_out)

id       id_number2      date2        check_out             
-----------------------------------------------------
10         10001      2018-02-04      22:09:09

11         10002      2018-02-04      22:09:21

12         10001      2018-02-05      09:21:22


Table 3 ( tbl_student )

id       id_number      Password       full_name             
-----------------------------------------------------
2          10001         10001           Alma

3          10002         10002          Daniel
```

[out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/067Mx.png)

```html
<?php
    include ("connection.php");
 $id = $_GET['employee-ID'];
 $query = "SELECT tbl_student.full_name,tbl_student.Id_Number, time.Id_Number1, time.date1 ,time.check_in, check_out.check_out  
           FROM tbl_student, time, check_out 
           WHERE check_out.Id_Number2 ='$id' AND time.Id_Number1 = '$id' AND  tbl_student.Id_Number =  '$id'";
 $result = mysqli_query ($link, $query) or die("select Error ".mysqli_error($link));
 $i = 1;
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  
?>
<tbody>   
    
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['full_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Id_Number']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['check_in'];  ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['check_out']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
 $i++;
 }
 mysqli_close  ($link);
?>
<p>
</p>
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9UyM.png)

```html
<?php
    include ("connection.php");
 $id = $_GET['employee-ID'];
 $query = "SELECT tbl_student.full_name, tbl_student.Id_Number, time.Id_Number1, time.date1, time.check_in,check_out.check_out, time.time_rn, check_out.check_out_rn
 
            FROM tbl_student ,(SELECT time.*, row_number() OVER ( partition by time.id_number1 order by time.date1) time_rn FROM time WHERE 1=1 ) 
   
         time, (SELECT check_out.*, row_number() OVER (partition by check_out.id_number2 order by check_out.date2) check_out_rn from check_out where 1=1) check_out 
   
            WHERE check_out.Id_Number2='$id' AND time.Id_Number1 ='$id' AND tbl_student.Id_Number = '$id' AND time_rn = check_out_rn (+)";
  
 $result = mysqli_query ($link, $query) or die("select Error ".mysqli_error($link));
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  
?>
```

Comment: Please format your question such that it contains readable stuff and not only code and links to images. Probably, this can be reduced to a simple SQL question....?

Comment: Please show us your table structure (columns, example data). How are the `time` and `check_out` tables related to each other? I assume that you want to match a check_out time with a check_in time somehow, but your SQL isn't doing that.

Comment: Please invest some time in making a clear question statement. Especially the sentence "This employee record in check-in and check-out column loopin or duplicate." needs some clarification.

Comment: @kfinity ,Yes bro..you are right.

There will be 2 different tables in database, check_in & check_out and for the outcome i wants the data to be generates in admin's system as one table which able to view particular employee check in/out base on  $id = $_GET['employee-ID']; .

Comment: thank for the responce @NicoHaase  , I re-edit the question .

Comment: @zx485 Hi, done edit the question.

Comment: Could you show us all the columns in `check_out`? Is it just `Id_Number2` and `check_out`, or are there more?

Comment: @kfinity Attached 3 tables which represent data for  
 table 1 = check_time ,
 table 2 = check_out ,table 3 = employee

The sql_query will pulls the data from this 3 table and the output will be appear in admin system .

But ,Currently in admin table , the data in check_in & check_out time  didnt sync with the data in admin system as it duplicate the time by calling from the first row to third row and sometimes the same times looping cotinuously for the upcoming days in table.

Comment: @kfinity may refer the image link  which the output   https://i.stack.imgur.com/067Mx.png . Kindly share your knowledge to solve it .

Comment: @kfinity , Hi Bro, Sorry for the late reply  and thanks alot for the clear explanation on the process .

Comment: @kfinity , Yes what you explain is correct. Thanks alot for the clear explanation on the process. I just modify the code on WHERE clause to   get " $id = $_GET['employee-ID']; " .                                                                                                                   There have error on "  FROM time WHERE 1=1 " .                                                                                                                                                                       Kindly find above sql code which i modify . Error Image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9UyM.png.

Comment: It looks like your version of MySQL doesn't support windowed aggregate functions. I updated my answer.

Comment: @kfinity. Thanks  bro . It's work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here's the thing. If you run your query, you'll see that it's just doing a **cross join** or *cartesian join* between the `time` and `check_out` tables. You almost never want this. It's showing every possible combination of the check_in and check_out times, because you haven't told it how the check_in and check_out times should be related.

```
select full_name, id_number, date1, check_in, check_out
from tbl_student, time, check_out
where id_number = 10001 and id_number1 = 10001 and id_number2 = 10001;

FULL_NAME  ID_NUMBER DATE1     CHECK_IN CHECK_OUT
--------- ---------- --------- -------- ---------
Alma           10001 04-FEB-18 22:07:59 22:09:09 
Alma           10001 04-FEB-18 22:07:59 09:21:22 
Alma           10001 05-FEB-18 08:21:10 22:09:09 
Alma           10001 05-FEB-18 08:21:10 09:21:22
```

In this case, I'm assuming you want it to *show the check_out time which matches the sequence of the check_in time for that user*. So the third check-in for a user should match up with their third check-out. To do that, I'm going to add a "row_number partitioned by the id_number" to each table, so we can match them up.

```
SELECT tbl_student.full_name, tbl_student.Id_Number, 
    time.Id_Number1, time.date1, time.check_in,
    check_out.check_out,
        time.time_rn, -- for testing
        check_out.check_out_rn -- for testing
  FROM tbl_student, 
    (select time.*,
        row_number() over (partition by time.id_number1 order by time.date1) time_rn
        from time where 1=1) time, 
    (select check_out.*,
        row_number() over (partition by check_out.id_number2 order by check_out.date2) check_out_rn
        from check_out where 1=1) check_out 
  WHERE check_out.Id_Number2=10001 AND time.Id_Number1 =10001 AND tbl_student.Id_Number = 10001
    and time_rn = check_out_rn (+)
  ;
```

Output:

```
FULL_NAME  ID_NUMBER ID_NUMBER1 DATE1     CHECK_IN CHECK_OUT    TIME_RN CHECK_OUT_RN
--------- ---------- ---------- --------- -------- --------- ---------- ------------
Alma           10001      10001 04-FEB-18 22:07:59 22:09:09           1            1
Alma           10001      10001 05-FEB-18 08:21:10 09:21:22           2            2
```

---

This is sort of an awkward table structure, by the way. If you can change the schema, I would recommend dropping the `check_out` table and doing something like this instead:

```
create table time (id number, 
                   id_number1 number, 
                   date1 date, 
                   check_in varchar2(8), 
                   check_out varchar2(8));
```

That way you could tell when someone hadn't checked out yet, since `time.check_out` would be null.

---

Edit: It looks like you're using a version of MySQL older than 8.0, which doesn't support windowed functions. Try this instead. In some ways it's a simpler query.

```
SELECT tbl_student.full_name, tbl_student.Id_Number, 
time.Id_Number1, time.date1, time.check_in,
(select min(check_out) 
  from check_out
  where Id_Number2=time.Id_Number1
    and check_out.date2 >= time.date1
    and check_out.check_out >= time.check_in) check_out
FROM tbl_student, time
WHERE time.Id_Number1 =10001 AND tbl_student.Id_Number = 10001;
```